# FusedLocationProviderClient RemoveLocationUpdatesAsync Task does not complete

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, task, fusedlocationproviderclient

I am implementing a Xamarin Android Location tracker and added following code to stop location updates.

```
    public Task StopAsync()
    {
        if(IsTracking)
        {
            IsTracking = false;
            perviousStopTask = fusedLocationProviderClient.RemoveLocationUpdatesAsync(this);
        }

        return perviousStopTask;
    }
```

Above method, I assign Task returns from `RemoveLocationUpdatesAsync` method to `perviousStopTask` and return it from `StopAsync` method. But when I try to await this `StopAsync` method it does not complete.

Comment: What do you mean it does not complete do you get an exception?

Comment: Please show more code about `RemoveLocationUpdatesAsync`.You can add breakpoints to check where the problem is.

Comment: @G.hakim When I try to call "await StopAsync()" method it is not completing the Task returns from this method. Which means application blocks at "await StopAsync()" method call.

Comment: If that was the case there would be am exception thrown right?

Comment: @G.hakim no, not if it dead-locks. From which thread are you calling this?

Comment: @Cheesebaron correct me if I am wrong but, For a deadlock, he needs to first be on a background thread right? But the code from what I see above is all synchronous!!! Also there is no context to the above code which makes it even harder to track the issue

Comment: I've also observed code after `await fusedLocationProviderClient.RemoveLocationUpdatesAsync(locationCallback)` doesn't execute. I tried this in an Android Service. Tested on Android O emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Xamarin [LocationSample project](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/blob/master/samples/com.google.android.gms/play-services-location/LocationSample/FusedLocationClientActivity.cs#L67) is placing blame on Google Play Services for this problem. The sample does not currently use await when calling `RemoveLocationUpdatesAsync`.

> TODO: We should await this call but there appears to be a bug in Google Play Services where the first time removeLocationUpdates is called, the returned Android.Gms.Tasks.Task never actually completes, even though location updates do seem to be removed and stop happening. For now we'll just fire and forget as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether Fused Location Provider is thread safe or not. However, you could try some of the following things.

1. It seems like you are returning a completed or a `null` when `IsTracking` is `false`, so I would change the method to:

   ```
   public Task StopAsync()
   {
       if (IsTracking)
       {
           IsTracking = false;
           return fusedLocationProviderClient.RemoveLocationUpdatesAsync(this);
       }

       return Task.CompletedTask;
   }
   ```
2. If you are not really interested in returning back to the context you called the method from, make sure you call `.ConfigureAwait(false)`:

   ```
   await StopAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
   ```